# AWS ASM describe-secret details and date resolution

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cloud, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to retrieve the secret details using aws CLI command, and I am able to get the details as well. But I am not able to understand the format in which dates are being retured.

```
{
    "RotationRules": {
        "AutomaticallyAfterDays": 90
    },
    "Name": "indextract/uat",
    "VersionIdsToStages": {
        "51b23a11-b871-40ec-a5f0-d4d3c90d781e": [
            "AWSCURRENT"
        ],
        "1f0b581b-4353-43d0-9163-f3a8a622b479": [
            "AWSPREVIOUS"
        ]
    },
    "Tags": [],
    "RotationEnabled": true,
    "LastChangedDate": 1596000798.137,
    "LastRotatedDate": 1595914104.584,
    "KmsKeyId": "XXX",
    "RotationLambdaARN": "XXX",
    "LastAccessedDate": 1595980800.0,
    "ARN": "XXX",
    "Description": "ZZZZ"
}
```

Can someone please help in interpreting `LastRotatedDate`, is there a cast function which I can use directly or on the field after parsing json?

May be a python or a unix command?

As a second part of question, my requirement is to get the new password only if it has changed. One way is to make first api call to get the LastChangeDate and then make `get-secret-value` call if required as per rotation days.

But this would need 2 api call, is there a way to do this in a single call? May be passing an argument like date and get response only if `LastChangedDate` is beyond the passed argument?

I could not find a way in doc, so though to take some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

LastChangedDate, LastRotatedDate and LastAccessedDate are all timestamp fields described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/secretsmanager/describe-secret.html)

In another word, they are epoch ones. I have tried using the conversion with your timestamp and the data is showing as
[image]

For the second question, I have not found direct way as you expected, but you can handle it based on some logic like.

1. Keep track 'timestamp' of the date you know the key get rotated, maybe using DynamoDB here to store it.
2. Based on the flag there you will decide your logic to see if you need to read a new password or not.
3. You can use Lambda, and CloudWatch rules to handle trigger and small logic for it.

But again, it takes efforts for that logic as well.

Could I ask you is that because of performance issue we want to reduce calling API everytime?

Thanks,